# Go OS file read sample from docs not working - declaration

Tags: go

I am reading the GO OS docs here https://golang.org/pkg/os/

The docs give this code

```
file, err := os.Open("file.go") // For read access.
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

and then this

```
data := make([]byte, 100)
count, err := file.Read(data)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

However when I use it in this example I get the non-declaration outside function body.

How should I be using the documentation code in this example?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "log"
  "os"
)

type doc struct {
    Meeting meeting `xml:"meeting"`
}

type meeting struct {
    Race race `xml:"race"`
}

type race struct {
    ID       int          `xml:"id,attr"`
    Name     string       `xml:"name,attr"`
    Distance int          `xml:"distance,attr"`
    Noms     []nomination `xml:"nomination"`
}

type nomination struct {
    Number int    `xml:"number,attr"`
    ID     int    `xml:"id,attr"`
    Horse  string `xml:"horse,attr"`
    Weight int    `xml:"weight,attr"`
    Rating int    `xml:"rating,attr"`
}

func main() {
    d := doc{}
    err := xml.Unmarshal(file, &d)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to unmarshal XML: %s\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", d)
}

file, err := os.Open("file.go") // For read access.
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
data := make([]byte, 100)
count, err := file.Read(data)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting tells you exactly what is wrong. Your code is outside a function body. Only declarations can be outside of function bodies. You'll need to move the code into main() or another function that main calls.

Comment: So should i put it in main or creatd a function for file reading based on the docs code?